# How can I uninstall git on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git

Can anyone tell me how can I uninstall git on the Eclipse. Whenever I open Eclipse it will popup and showing some errors. I want to uninstall it from the eclipse, please can anyone help me out in this regards.

Comment: eclipse doesn't contain git integration by default, so you need to clarify what you mean.

Comment: did you get it managed to uninstall it?

Comment: @eis It does, usually, these days - http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php

Comment: As a quick fix, If you just want to disable Git in a project: `right click on a project name -> Team -> Disconnect`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To uninstall the EGit Plugin do the following:

**Help** > **Eclipse Marketplace...** > **Installed** Tab > **EGit** > **uninstall**

Comment: You may need to select a Marketplace that matches where it was installed from. Most likely the "Yoxos Marketplace"

Comment: thanks. although i had to search it on the market, then uninstall. the installed tab doesn't seem to show everything.

Comment: Uninstall doesn't work, says it is "required by other packages".

Answer (score 1):

**Help > Eclipse Marketplace... > Installed Tab > EGit > uninstall**

Comment: the question is about removing a Git plugin from Eclipse, not about removing anything from his operating system